# Why do I need an ItemReader in my job step if I only need to delete rows using ItemWriter

Tags: spring-batch

I have a step in my batch job that I want to use only to delete rows from a table.

The step looks like this:

```
@Bean 
    public Step step2(StepBuilderFactory factory,
                      PurgeAggBalanceWriter writer,
                      DataSource dataSource,
                      PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager){
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step2")
                .transactionManager(platformTransactionManager)
                .<Assessment,Assessment>chunk(10)
                .reader(getReader(dataSource, READER_QUERY2, "AggBalanceMapper", new AggBalanceMapper()))
                .writer(writer)
                .build();
    }
```

I am using this writer class with a jdcb template to run the delete statement:

```
public class PurgeAggBalanceWriter implements ItemWriter<Assessment> {
   
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    private static final String DELETE_QUERY = "DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN = 'TEST'";

    public PurgeAggBalanceWriter(DataSource dataSource) {

        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }


    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends Assessment> list) {

        jdbcTemplate.update(DELETE_QUERY);

}
```

The step completes successfully but I dont see why an ItemReader is required as it states when I try to remove the .reader() from step2.

Is there a way to avoid using a reader/mapper and just using the writer since all I have to do is run a delete query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> all I have to do is run a delete query

In this case, you don't need a chunk-oriented tasklet. A simple tasklet is enough, something like:

```
public class DeletionTasklet implements Tasklet {

    private static final String DELETE_QUERY = "DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN = 'TEST'";
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public DeletionTasklet(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) {
        jdbcTemplate.update(DELETE_QUERY);
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }
}
```

Comment: Howdy Mahmoud, 
I tested this when deleting a small amount of rows and it seems to work fine although when I use this solution to delete a large amount of rows I get an sql rollback exception:
*com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlNonTransientConnectionException: [jcc][t4][10335][10366][4.14.113] Invalid operation: Connection is closed. ERRORCODE=-4470, SQLSTATE=08003
*

Comment: Seems to be running into a deadlock condition somehow...
The Task works fine when I run it against a small amount of rows but will eventually need to delete thousands of rows which is when I run into this issue...

Comment: According to the error, the connection seems to be closed while your query is running. I'm not a db2 expert, but you need to configure your db2 to allow long running queries. On the Spring Batch side, the tasklet will be executed in a transaction which you can configure using the step builder `transactionAttribute()` method (timeout, isolation, propagation, etc).

Comment: no need to duplicate similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64213585/is-there-something-i-can-add-to-the-task-so-it-can-handle-deleting-thousands-of. It is more efficient to keep related things in the same thread.

Comment: Would it be advisable to handle the data in chunks to avoid the timeout?

Comment: No, no need to read data to delete it. Using a tasklet is the way to go to issue a single delete query to the db. Your issue is a matter of configuration.

Comment: Looks like the DB can't be configured as stated by the DB team...
Is there a way to handle the commits in chunks or something similar while still using a tasklet?